# How to relace byte of 32bit variable in inline assembly?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly, avr

I want to replace the highest byte of 32bit value with inline assembly, following code writes buffer to FRAM memory with spi interace:

```
#define _load_op_code(op_code, addr)\
  __asm__ __volatile__ (\
  " ldi %D0, %1"     "\n\t"\
  : "=d"  ((uint32_t)addr)\
  : "M" (op_code)\
  )

#define SMEM_WREN   0x06
#define SMEM_WRITE  0x02

void fram_write(uint32_t addr, uint8_t *buf, uint16_t len) {
  FRAM_SELECT();
  spi_send_char(SMEM_WREN);
  FRAM_DESELECT();
  _load_op_code(SMEM_WRITE, addr);
  FRAM_SELECT();
  spi_send_32b(addr);
  spi_send(buf, len);
  FRAM_DESELECT();
}
```

after _load_op_code() inline assembly addr variable gets cluttered - compiler use registers allocated for addr as temporary registers for other operations and i lose original addr value. addr is in fact 24bit variable. Any idea whats wrong with this code?

Comment: could not catch your idea exactly. AFAIK,actually 'ldi' should operate immediate values, however the operand you provided here by %1 is a memory address, would this matter?

Comment: "M" constrain describes op_code as 8-bit integer constant, i have added use case which is much more clear i hope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original value of addr is lost because it is overwritten by the asm statement with SMEM_WRITE and 3 undefined bytes. From the GCC manual:

> The ordinary output operands must be write-only; GCC assumes that the values in these operands before the instruction are dead and need not be generated. Extended asm supports input-output or read-write operands. Use the constraint character ‘+’ to indicate such an operand and list it with the output operands.